Do I need to create a proposal on OpenGov in order to open an HRMP channel?
I'm not sure if this is the right question to ask, but do I need to create a proposal on OpenGov in order to open an HRMP channel between Kusama AssetHub and my Parachain?
Any insights or resources would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much! 

This wiki page should answer your question: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-hrmp-channels#opening-hrmp-channels-with-system-parachains

Nice. Thank you so much!
